# SQL return only rows that are unique in one column

Tags: sql

how to get all the rows where col2 is unique.  I just want to return one row if there is a duplicate in col2.

```
 col1  col2 
  1c     a 
  2b     a
  33     a
  4b     b
  5k     c
  68     c
```

results:

```
 col1  col2
  1c      a
  4b      b
  5k      c
```

Comment: `I just want to return one row if...` - Which one?

Comment: @dragoste . . . If there is only one, there is only one to return.

Comment: return just the 1st one it finds.

Comment: Do you want the rows where `col2` is unique, or do you want all the values in `col2` with duplicates removed? I.e. do you want only the record with `b` from your example, or records for `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: i want a, b, c returned that is unique, with the first value for col1.

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Comment: @FuzzyTree its because the op didn't ask it correctly at first

Comment: @user1929393 You've asked to _return just the 1st one it finds_. Data in a table is not inherently ordered. You need to specify which one you would want to be first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the distinct values from `col2` you can group on that.

To get values for other columns you use aggregates to determine which value in each group to choose. As you want the first value from `col1` that would be the lowest value, so you can use the `min` aggregate:

```
select
  min(col1) as col1,
  col2
from
  TheTable
group by
  col2
order by
  col2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name1,column_name2 FROM table_name;
```

W3School Tutorial [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: `DISTINCT column_name1,column_name2`Will consider uniqueness for both coloumns but he asked for unique col2.